# Windows 7 taskbar - transparency effect

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

I'm having a problem that I can't solve. Somehow the taskbar on Windows 7 is translucent or transparent, making it impossible to see the end of any web page on any browsers. How can I restore it to the default?

Comment: So, the issue is that your maximized windows are displaying behind the task bar, instead of on top or above?

Comment: If it's transparent, then how is it preventing you from seeing the web page? :) Have you tried (re)setting your Windows appearance/themes, colors etc.? (Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Personalization)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on your task bar, click Properties, and check "auto-hide the taskbar".  Click Apply.  Go back into the same screen, uncheck "auto-hide the taskbar" and click Apply.  How's that look?